# Precondition for executing Xorg -configure and postcondition how to use its output?

Tags: 11.04, xorg

Action: Open a terminal window from Ubuntu 11.04 Desktop and execute `sudo Xorg -configure`.
The command Xorg -configure returns an error message because the X server is running.
How do I stop the XServer safely and restart it again afterwards ?

What is the output of Xorg -configure - a text file ?

What do I do with the output of Xorg -configure to reconfigure my XServer ?

Comment: Hello, this question has no information and activity for a very long time. I am closing it for now. If by any reason you think this question is still viable or useful in anyway or that there is still a good chance it will be answered please flag it to a moderator or add a comment with the reason(s) why you want it open. Regards